# ads in android application

Tags: android, security, ads, google-play

I have created an android application.
After I installed it from the Google play store on my device, I found an ad for another application on the main activity, and then later another ad and shortcuts...
I found many solutions for that issue, all of them come as configurations and settings.
It's not enough,  as a developer I am looking to stop all kind of advertisements that show up on my app, is it a matter of security? or permissions?
I suppose there must be a permission to allow such things to show up on your application, and if you didn't give such permission that ads can never break in.

If some one knows how to do that, I'll appreciate any help.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you use an in-app advertising platform you can not necessarily control the things they might do in your app (you are adding their library into your source, and it becomes part of your application).

If you have not included external libraries, it is not possible for another application to add ads, or icons via your code.  To be clear, Ads can NEVER 'break in' to your app if you have not included the Ad Platform library in your Android project.

Bottom line, if you are worried about malicious software becoming part of your application, don't use any external libraries you don't trust (or that you don't fully know what they do).